# what happens if Firestore limitation has been Broken

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have read in Firestore documentation that Firestore can handle 10,000 writes/sec and 1 million simultaneous connection

What happens exactly there if there is was new continuous read and write operations WHILE limitation has been Broken at the same time? Will the operations be delayed with treatment until the pressure is relieved again and then treated, or will it never arrive?

In other word What happens to new reads and writes that occur at the same moment the restrictions are broken?

A simple example: if user call one of these methods WHILE limitation has been Broken at the same time, and there a big pressure on server with millions users:

```
.get()
.set()
.update() etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas), you can exceed the 10,000 writes/sec and 1 million simultaneous connections and the app will continue working.  But if this limit is exceeded, it would greatly affect latency, performance and error rate.

requests above the free quota limit will get rejected. With the following error - RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded.

Here is some [relevant information](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/troubleshooting)